# How to override the default dir alias in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, alias

I wanted to see colorized filenames when I typed dir in Powershell. So, I added the **Set-ChildItemColor** function from [here](http://tasteofpowershell.blogspot.sg/2009/02/get-childitem-dir-results-color-coded.html) to my profile file. I also added this line at the end of the profile file to override the dir alias:

```
Set-Alias dir Get-ChildItemColor
```

Now, when I open Powershell, I get this error:

```
Set-Alias : The AllScope option cannot be removed from the alias 'dir'.
At C:\Users\joe\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:82
char:10
+ Set-Alias <<<<  dir Get-ChildItemColor
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (dir:String) [Set-Alias], SessionStateUna
   uthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AliasAllScopeOptionCannotBeRemoved,Microsoft.PowerShe
   ll.Commands.SetAliasCommand
```

What is this **AllScope**? How do I remove that option to get colorized dir?

Comment: Not sure why this was closed.. I had exactly this ("AllScope option cannot be removed") and the answer below solved my problem.

Answer (score 36):

Use the -Option parameter of Set-Alias.

```
Set-Alias -Name dir -Value Set-ChildItemColor -Option AllScope
```

See Get-Help Set-Alias and Get-Help about_Scope for details.